# USB set to /dev/sda instead of /dev/sdb

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, system-installation, usb, kickstart

I've been trying to use a kickstart file to guide the Red Hat installer (RHEL6.5) without user intervention. It correctly looks for the kickstart file in `/dev/sdb/fs.cfg`, but because the USB is recognized as `/dev/sda`, it is actually located at `/dev/sda/fs.cfg`. I can manually point the installer to this destination, but the rest of kickstart file relies on having the native hard drive be `sda`. I would like to do so without editing the kickstart files, but that's what is necessary, I'm willing to do it.

Is there any way to force the kernel to recognize the USB as `sdb` and the HD as `sda` (I'm assuming the kernel is responsible for the mix up, but I'm not sure)? It seems very odd that it chooses an external drive (the USB) as `sda` and forces the internal (HD) to `sdb.`

Note: My issue is very similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18155/change-dev-sd-for-usb-linux-install), except that my kickstart file absolutely depends on the HD being `sda`

This problem only occurs for RHEL6.5 installer and not for RHEL5.X installer (I haven't tried any previous version of RHEL6.X). What I really want to know is why it is changes between versions.

Comment: It's not the kernel that's mixed up, it's whoever wrote the kickstart file.  However, you can probably avoid this problem by booting *without the USB attached*, then after the system is up, plug it in.

Comment: BTW, I dunno how you end up with `/dev/sd[anything]/whatever` -- unless I'm about to learn something new, this should **not** be a real path.  Files are in filesystems, not device nodes.

Comment: I considered this, but I wasn't sure on the timing. I guess I should just keep trying different time intervals until I get a successful install boot with USB as sdb.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that when a path like `/dev/sdX` is given manually (or through kickstart file) during installation, the kernel (or some other software) automatically chooses a mount point to load the files on.

Comment: @goldilocks has the only valid solution here if you are really focused on using the `/dev` reference. However, you should consider using consistent device names (e.g., labels or UUIDs).

Comment: *"It correctly looks for the kickstart file in `/dev/sdb/fs.cfg`"* -> Unless you have an explicit source of information to the contrary (I'm not intimate w/ kickstarter stuff), this has to be wrong (I'm saying this to save you some frustration).  `/dev/sdb` is a **device node**.  You might mount this, e.g., `mount /dev/sdb /mnt/whatever`, and then you could access `/mnt/whatever/fs.cfg`, but normally, `/dev/sdb` is a dead stop in a path, because, again, it is not a directory, and cannot be used like a directory.

Comment: @HalosGhost I've seen some `sed` commands that substitutes 'UUID' for 'LABELS' in `/etc/fstab`(the `sed` commands are in a newer version of the kickstart) I'll add these commands to my kickstart.
@goldilocks Whenever it fails to load the kickstart file the installer gives the user a choice of where is it located. Either in `sda` or `sdb`. While I do agree that `/dev/sdb/fs.cgf` would normally be impossible because `/dev/sdb` is a dead stop, it appears to work (somehow) during installation.

Comment: @goldilocks I tried plugging the USB in at different times during the boot up, but it didn't help. If I waiting too long, the machine would boot from native HD and ignore the USB installer. If I plugged it in too earlier, it would launch the installer but set the USB to `sda` which is a problem for the kickstart files.

Comment: In other words, whoever wrote those kickstart files either: 1) Did not intend them for use on a USB stick, or 2) Did not know what they are doing.  If the drive order is set by the BIOS and that's determined by the boot order, then if you boot from USB that's `/dev/sda`.  Whoops ;)

Comment: Actually kernel version caused this kind of problem.When you used kernel 2.6.x. Kernel 2.6.x will detect usb disk as /dev/sda. When you used kernel 3.x.Kernel 3.x will detect usb disk as /dev/sdb.Because I compiled kernel 3.x on SL 6.8. And I can see a different between kernel 2.6.x and kernel 3.x when detected usb disk.

Comment: If I am not mistaken. Elrepo got kernel 3.18.x for centos 6.5.You can install it.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so here's the way the boot process works:

- firmware > bootloader *maybe* > kernel `${parameters}` > initramfs > userspace *maybe*

On a redhat installation disk their *dracut* system of scripts is what builds and constitutes initramfs and their *anaconda* installation system constitutes the final userspace.

It is `udev` that handles the device setup - as in, it names the devices in `/dev`. But this almost always happens *twice* - once in initramfs and again when the `init` within has found its target root device and is ready to mount a `devfs` on it.

So this is how it works:

- bootloader *(or firmware)* invokes the kernel with an optional parameter set and an optional initramfs image. This parameter set is saved in `/proc/cmdline` and the kernel ignores all parameters it doesn't understand.
- The initramfs is a working linux userspace. Whether its `/` contents are unpacked from an image handed it at invocation or they are compiled in doesn't matter - since kernel 2.6 it is always the first working root filesystem the linux kernel mounts. From this point the linux kernel leaves it all to userspace.

  - Usually *(as is true for redhat's dracut)* the initramfs contains only what is absolutely necessary to find a root device and mount it over itself. Generally all that is included is `busybox` and the kernel modules required to mount your target root device.
  - It probably needs `udev` to do that though, so `udev` is most often included - with its own tiny little set of rules.
  - As mentioned, initramfs is its own little complete linux root filesystem. A complete one might look like: `/bin /etc /dev /new_root /proc /sys init`. There's generally nothing very unusual about any of the contents of these directories - there's almost always a `/bin/sh` and an `/etc/fstab`.
  - Most `init`s will parse `/proc/cmdline` for any kernel parameters they might interpret. A very common one is `root=/dev/somedisk` or `root=UUID=somediskUUID` or `root=LABEL=somedisklabel`. It is the initramfs `init` that interprets these `root=...` parameters - not the kernel or the final `init` execed later *(though the final one may very well interpret others)*. It will accept this parameter and mount it on `/new_root` *(or whatever name it uses for the staging mount before it `switchroot`s)*. If `udev` is included in initramfs then it is the initramfs ruleset that decides what that target disk's `/dev/...` entry is named for now - but that can change.
  - When the initramfs `init` successfully finds and mounts the `/new_root` device it usually looks for something to `exec` itself into - usually `/new_root/bin/init` - so whatever that program is becomes pid 1. It usually does this with the `switch_root` program provided with `busybox` - which does an `exec` while simultaneously mounting `/new_root` *over* `/`. Its process is described in the [kernel docs thus](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt):

  > But initramfs *is* rootfs: you can neither `pivot_root` rootfs, nor `umount` it. Instead delete everything out of rootfs to free up the space *(`find -xdev / -exec rm '{}' ';'`)*, overmount rootfs with the new root *(`cd /newmount; mount --move . /; chroot .`)*, attach `stdin/stdout/stderr` to the new `/dev/console`, and `exec` the new `init`.
- The root device `init` just execed now has to populate its own root filesystem. It calls its `udev` and mounts its own `devfs` on `/dev` based on its own ruleset and does all the rest. When it's through you are ready to use your computer.

Sorry for the level of detail there, but I wanted to make it clear why the following is true:

- any kernel parameter you hand in from the bootloader like `root=/dev/sda` *doesn't have* to be the same `/dev/sda` that you will eventually access on `/dev/sda` after the initramfs `/init` is through.

So one way to do this, I think, is to set a `udev` rule on your *anaconda* disk - which is actually a squashfs archive, probably - that instructs it to setup all usb disks somewhere else. There's an [excellent example here:](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#example-usbhdd)

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="USB 2.0 Storage Device", SYMLINK+="usbhd%n"
```

And it would be a very good thing if you read the rest of that link as well. You should be able to do that so your usb disk device is `/dev/sda` for initramfs - so you don't have to change any bootloader configurations - but then later creates a node for the same disk as `/dev/usba` for the anaconda install system.

Answer (score 3):

go into the BIOS of the host and rearrange the order of the hard drives and removable drives. This will adjust the order as it appears to the Linux kernel.

Comment: Rearrange the boot order? Or is there another option in the BIOS to rearrange the order it 'finds' the drives.

Comment: Different BIOSes are different; you'll need to play around with it.

Comment: The only options I could find were related to boot order. The default has "All USB HD" as the first drive to boot from. Moving the native HD to the top makes the machine boot into the current OS and it does not run the RHEL installer at all. =[

Comment: Yeah, some BIOSes are more limited than others.

Answer (score 1):

On my shiny new but ancient $45 HP G60 laptop I was having the same issue. I made USB move from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb` by putting the new SSD first in the boot order. Then on boot, press ESC like you're going into BIOS but there is a preBIOS menu. So instead of hitting F10 to enter BIOS, I pressed F9 for BOOT OPTIONS. Then in there you can manually choose to boot from USB regardless of BOOT ORDER set in BIOS. Obviously I chose the USB and then on installation my SSD was showing as `/dev/sda`.

I've searched and searched and many people have similar problems but no one suggested that. Much simpler than anything else I found. I discovered that on a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in RHEL6 you can use labels for your install media such that you access the drive/hd by a unique name not the inconsistent kernel sdX naming.

When you create the file systems on your USB drive make sure to label them with something like e2label or the 101 other ways to label the file system.

Once labeled you can access the USB by that name ex: ks=hd:LABEL=yourname:/path/to/fs.ks

Also keep in mind this type of naming can be used for other locations as well.  install media, repos, etc...